# Highchart render in pdf generated using PHP mPdf

Tags: php, highcharts, mpdf

Can anybody suggest me what should I do ?
I am generating the PDF report and in the report, I have to print the high chart graph. As high chart uses the javascript which will not execute in PDF file, So I have to create the graph on the server.

I read many posts, they suggest me that i have to create the image of that graph, but my question is how will I create the image to that graph ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using server-side "browser" or JS engine to generate your graphs; there are tools that can be used for that.

For that purpose I used those:

- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org): some quirks regarding header/footers but a nice lot of examples on website
- [WkHTMLToPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org): highly customisable, but I had trouble setting timeouts properly so graphs are fully generated before PDF output

But there are others.

Answer (score 1):

As Preuk says, phantomjs is a good choice and what I use, here's a guide to it on the Highcharts site: http://www.highcharts.com/news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs
It can be fiddly to get going but works well once you get it up and running.